# what is the reason for "Anonymous class only implement the interface or extend the class but not both" in java?

Tags: java, oop

I have read Anonymous class can only implement the interface or extend the class but not both. But I don't know what is the key reason behind it to prevent both at the same time?

Please enlighten me on this...

Comment: How could you possibly have it do both? Show the code where this is even attempted.

Comment: Where did you read about it? Hopefully not on www.roseindia.net ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because anonymous class basically doesnt has any name. So you basically cannot write

```
Class someClass extends SomeOtherClass implements SomeInterface
```

you do it like

```
new SomeClass/SomeInterface(){
  @override
  public void someMethod(){
  }
};
```